# Basic java logic expression is incorrect

Tags: java

This code should return a Long the first time. But it returns a Double. It's gotta be something basic but I can't find it. (And in the debugger, using the evaluate a line command, it works as expected.)

What am I missing?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class WeirdResult {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Number num = valueOf("1");
        System.out.println("this first one should be a Long");
        System.out.println("1 - class = " + num.getClass() + ", value = " + num);

        num = valueOf("1.0");
        System.out.println("1.0 - class = " + num.getClass() + ", value = " + num);
    }

    public static Number valueOf(String strNumber) {

        Number num = isUseDecimal() ? new BigDecimal(strNumber) :
                (strNumber.indexOf('.') == -1 ? Long.valueOf(strNumber) : new Double(strNumber));
        return num;
    }

    private static boolean isUseDecimal() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The output is:

this first one should be a Long

1 - class = class java.lang.Double, value = 1.0

1.0 - class = class java.lang.Double, value = 1.0

I expect it to be:

this first one should be a Long

1 - class = class java.lang.Long, value = 1

1.0 - class = class java.lang.Double, value = 1.0

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? What is the output you're getting and how does it differ from what you would expect?

Comment: @Tunaki - sorry, I should have included the output. I just added that.

Comment: @ SotiriosDelimanolis - that's it, the duplication you pointed to.